# Swift passing key path as a param of func

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, swift-keypath

I need to be able to pass #keypath to a func to filter my CoreData records.

I do smth like this:

```
func filteredExercises(with propertyKeyPath: #keyPath, filter: Any) {

        do {
            let filteredExercises = try CoreStore.fetchAll(
                From<ExerciseEntity>(),
                Where<ExerciseEntity>("%K = %@", #keyPath(ExerciseEntity.muscle.name), filter)
            )

        } catch {

        }
    }
```

But for sure #keyPath is not a type, how to do it correctly? Or Do I need to prepare a filtered string which I will pass to a func like a predicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to work with `#keyPath`, then it's just a String.
(A little safer form of creating a String intended to work with KVC.)

Declare the parameter type as `String`, where you want to receive `#keyPath`, and pass it to anywhere `#keyPath` is accepted.

```
func filteredExercises(with propertyKeyPath: String, filter: Any) {

    do {
        let filteredExercises = try CoreStore.fetchAll(
            From<ExerciseEntity>(),
            Where<ExerciseEntity>("%K = %@", propertyKeyPath, filter)
        )

    } catch {

    }
}
```

If you need to work with Swift-native `KeyPath`, that's another issue.